# r program bayes.glmm giving an error Error in prep_call_sampler(object)

Tags: bayesian, glmmtmb

I am running bayes.glmm r package but it is giving an error:

> data("sample", package = "bayes.glmm")
> pheno = data$pheno
> geno = data$geno
> cov = data$cov
> L <- t(chol(data$K))
> mymodel = stan_models(model = "glm", auto_write = TRUE)
> y2 = myGWAS_fit(model = mymodel, method = "sampling", type = "categorical", cov = cov, geno = geno[c(1, 3), ], pheno = pheno)

Error in prep_call_sampler(object) :
the compiled object from C++ code for this model is invalid, possible reasons:

- compiled with save_dso=FALSE;
- compiled on a different platform;
- does not exist (created from reading csv files).

I couldn't find any solution on google. How can I get rid of this error. I've installed and uninstalled rstan and bayes.glmm packages many times which couldn't solve the problem.
Thanks,
Vinod

Comment: It's difficult to help you without the data or a reproducible example. And `bayes.glmm` hasn't been updated for over 2 years, but `stan` has changed significantly since then...

Comment: @meriops  Yes, you are right.